# Hybrid app - is it possible to upload a large binary file to Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a web-app where the user clicks on a button and selects a .zip file.
The zip file is then returned as File object to Javascript which further processes the file.

I have a hybrid version of the web-app, on Android.
The zip file is stored on the mobile device,
Is it possible to pass the .zip file to the Javascript where it can do some of the processing?

Thanks

Comment: If you can pass a string to that javascript then yes i would say.

Comment: The file size can reach ~1GB, so I don't think a string is an option.
With pure a web-app a portion of the file is returned as bytearray within a blob.
With mobile hybrid, the closest I found was to intercept the fetch in shouldInterceptRequest and return the portion of the file via bytearray as WebResourceResponse.

Comment: A string that contains only file path of course. Javascrip could not handle the uri you said. So you made a copy of the file in order to have a file system path that you would tell javascript.